# rsyslogd used with any application or only Linux system logging?

Tags: logs, rsyslog

Is the purpose of rsyslogd to handle logging of applications in userspace? For example i have 5 Jboss instances running on a server with custum applications running inside them. They all produce there own logfiles. I now want to aggregate the 5 files into one and send this aggregated stream of logfiles out on the network. Is this sort of thing what rsyslogd is constructed for?

Answer (score 0):

Rsyslog can be used for this purpose, yes. It was designed as a drop-in replacement for `syslogd`, and it's quite common to use syslog for application logging like this.